# How to make a conditional button that changes the screen view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode12

I am new to Swift, but I am trying to make a simple blackjack game. I have a **HIT** button that adds a card to the player's hand and increases the player's total score each time. But I also want to add a condition to the **HIT** button that if the player's total is over 21 a new screen appears with the text "You lose". However, I cannot get the button to open another view.

I at first thought to change the **HIT** button to a **NavigationView** but then I couldn't figure out where to add the **ifBust** condition, so I thought it would better solution to make a new **.swift** file and call the file name in the **if** statement, that does not seem to work either.

I have a **isBust** function that returns true if the player's score is over 21:

```
func isBust(score:Int) -> Bool {
 if (score > 21) {
  return true
 }
 return false
}
```

And in another swift file, I have the "You Lose" screen titled "**LooserView.swift**"

```
import SwiftUI
struct LosserVew: View {
 var body: some View {
  Text("You loose!")
 }
}
struct LooserView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
  LooserView()
 }
}
```

And lastly, I have the **HIT** Button:

```
// action = deals 1 card to player and increases player count then checks if player is bust

Button(action:{
 let randomSuit:String = suits[Int.random(in:0 ...  3)] 
  // calls the 'suit' array, and returns a random suit: clubs, diamonds, hearts, or spades
 let randomNumb:Int = Int.random(in: 1 ... 13) // calls a random card number
 playerCard = String(randomSuit) + String(randomNumb) // updates the player's card
 playerScore += randomNumb // adds to the player's current score

 if (isBust(score: playerScore)) {
  // if true, meaning the player's score is over 21, load the "You Lose" screen
 }
}, label: {
Text("HIT")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer to my own question. First I need to add a selection variable with **nil** (also meaning null?) as its value within the file.

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @State private var selection:String? = nil
  var body: some View {}
}
```

Note that **ContentView** is just the name of the **.swift** file.

Then, I need to insert a **NavigationView** in the body of the **.swift** file.

```
struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
   // the body/design of the code
  } // End of NavView
 }
}
```

Next, I need to add a **NavigationLink** inside the "design" of the code (i.e.: under the first Z, H, or VStack present). And attach a tag to the navigation link. So when I update the selection to match the tag and it will cause the appropriate **NavigationLink** to activate.

```
struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
   // the body/design of the code
   ZStack() {
    NavigationLink(destination: LooserView(), tag: "A", selection: $selection) {}
    // destination = LooserView.swift file, the tag of the nav-link is called "A"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

And lastly, within the **HIT** button in the **ifBust** conditional, I update the selection to **A** if **ifBust** returns true (a.k.a: the score is over 21).

```
if (isBust(score: playerScore)) {
 selection = "A"
}
```

[How to use programmatic navigation in SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-programmatic-navigation-in-swiftui) <- this article helped me a lot with this problem